# Printing values from a stored procedure

Tags: c++, sql, stored-procedures, solaris, sybase

I have an application which is written in c++.
I am using sybase libraries to call a stored procedure.
I have the traces from my c++ files but not from the stored procedure.
below is the way i am calling the stored procedure from cpp file.

```
dbcmd(_bsmdb, (char*)sp_cmd);
dbsqlexec(_bsmdb);
```

sp_cmd is the complete string execution of sp like exec sp_name args.
so i want to  put print statements inside the SP and see the results on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In the SP you can use `selects` to print what you want as a result.

In the c++ side, it depends on the sybase lybary that you are using.